# Anyway to make the host stop echoing code for google analytics while uploading an image using ShareX?

Tags: php, google-analytics, image-uploading, image-upload

I've got this script for uploading an image to my own website using ShareX, I have it hosted on 000webhost because I have no disposable income to waste on webhosting for personal stuff.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/text");



$key = "...";
$uploadhost = "http://quietess.xyz/";
$redirect = "http://quietess.xyz/";

if (isset($_POST['k'])) {
    if ($_POST['k'] == $key) {
        $target = getcwd() . "/" . basename($_FILES['d']['name']);
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['d']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
            $md5 = md5_file(getcwd() . "/" . basename($_FILES['d']['name']));
            rename(getcwd() . "/" . basename($_FILES['d']['name']), getcwd() . "/i/" . $md5 . "." . end(explode(".", $_FILES["d"]["name"])));
            echo $uploadhost . "i/" . $md5 . "." . end(explode(".", $_FILES["d"]["name"]));
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
        }
    } else {
        header('Location: '.$redirect);
    }
} else {
    header('Location: '.$redirect);
}
?>
```

[And this is what my ShareX custom settings look like](http://quietess.xyz/i/56a5fd9d02da0c8bddab8086cb7b317d.png)

It works very well, but then I have a problem when it comes to my webhosting...

It echos the link back like this (which is put in my clipboard for easy copy and pasting)

```
http://quietess.xyz/i/b7f7fdc250298436af47afefc774d02e.png
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

Is there any way to make it stop putting the Analytics code at the end like that?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find an answer using code, but finally got an answer on their forums after about a day. There's a spot on their site (completely hidden, apparently) to disable analytics.

https://members.000webhost.com/analytics.php